# Make `citation()` print both text and BibTeX for two sources

Tags: r, package

## Situation

I am writing the `CITATION` file for an R package. When I build and install the package, I can successfully use the `citation()` function to either

a) print the citation of my package in both plain text and BibTeX format (the default for `citation("mypkg")`), or

b) print the plain text citation for two entries, my package and a journal article.

## Goal

I would like to have `citation("mypkg")` print both the plain text *and* the BibTeX format for *both* the package and the journal article.

## Code:

To print both formats for the package, my `CITATION` file includes only

```
# Generate citation from DESCRIPTION:
citation(auto = meta)
```

To print only plain text for both sources, my `CITATION` file includes

```
# Generate citation from DESCRIPTION:
citation(auto = meta)

bibentry(bibtype = "Article",
         title = "My Title",
         author = person(c("R.", "T."), "M"),
         journal = "Journal X",
         volume = 1,
         number = 1,
         pages = "1-2",
         year = 2023,
         note = "",
         doi = "")
```

This is a long-extant package, so at this time I am not using `roxygen` for documentation.

Thanks in advance for any help.